# Comments generation in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way without typing /** that I can generate comment template for the entire class? I have 50 methods in the class and it gets tedious to type /** for each and every method and specifying the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAutodoc can do this: http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/